# $ P[A] \leq P[A |\bar B] + P[B] $

Tags: probability, probability-theory

How to prove that for any two events $A$ and $B$

$$ P[A] \leq P[A |\bar B] + P[B] $$

Can someone provide me hint how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

$P(A) = P(A\cap B) + P(A\cap \overline{B}) \leq P(B) + P(A|\overline{B})P(\overline{B}) \leq P(B) + P(A|\overline{B})$

Answer (score 2):

By [law of total probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_probability):

$\mathbb{P}\left( A \right) = \underbrace {\mathbb{P}\left( {A|B} \right)}_{ \leqslant 1}\mathbb{P}\left( B \right) + \mathbb{P}\left( {A|\overline B } \right)\underbrace {\mathbb{P}\left( {\overline B } \right)}_{ \leqslant 1} \leqslant \mathbb{P}\left( B \right) + \mathbb{P}\left( {A|\overline B } \right)$